# Phonegap localstorage undefIned

Tags: cordova

Using phonegap 2.0 i can't figure out why window.localstorage is returning undefined. Window.device works perfect but when I do a console.log of window.localstorage it is undefined and I have no idea why. I made sure i added the plugin to the xml (I'm working with Android). Any help is much appreciated. I feel like it's something very simple but I'm just not seeing it.

here is a code snippet of the index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="phonegap/android.js"></script>
        <script src="js/childbrowser.js"></script>
        <script>        

            document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            }, false);

            document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){

                alert(window.localstorage);

            }, false);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- DEVELOPMENT -->
        <script src="libs/zepto.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/underscore.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/backbone.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/iscroll.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of how you are trying to use it?

Comment: Are you setting any key/values to localStorage?  If so I don't see that anywhere in your code... take a look at the code snippet I've added below.  The two functions handle setting and getting of the key/values within the localStorage object.  I've also included how I've used these two functions within an app when I load and save users preferences.

Comment: I found the issue. The s in storage needs to be a capital S. Talk about feeling stupid!!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a couple of functions that I use in just about all of my apps making it a bit easier when dealing with user Preferences...

```
function getPref(iKey, iDefault){
    try{
        var R = window.localStorage.getItem(iKey);
        if (R==null || R=='') {return iDefault;} else {return R;}
    }catch(e){return iDefault;}     
}

function setPref(iKey, iData){
    window.localStorage.setItem(iKey, iData);
}
```

Usage:

```
// on load user preferences procedure
$('#GPSCheckbox').val(getPref('UseGPS','off'));
$('#WiFiCheckbox').val(getPref('WiFiOnly','on'));


// on save user preferences procedure
setPref('UseGPS',$('#GPSCheckbox').val());
setPref('WiFiOnly',$('#WiFiCheckbox').val());
```

I hope this helps you with your situation...